# Check for unused roles in Chef Server

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I was wondering if there were a way to check for roles that have not been assigned to any nodes in the Chef Server through a Ruby script.

Thanks

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment why? The question seems specific enough to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, the best approach would be to do a search to grab the `roles` attribute for every node on your server and then `|` those together and compare to the list of role names.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I wanted to be able to run this through a Ruby script. I'm assuming you meant `|` as in the pipe special character in Unix?

Comment: No, I meant it in terms of Ruby, `Array#|` in Ruby does a set union operation which is what you want to do.